# Hibernate issue: List containing null values instead of the actual values returned by my ORACLE query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, plsql, hibernate-criteria

I'm having issues with Hibernate. Let's say to create my table in SQL I have:

```
CREATE TABLE "SOMETHING_TABLE"
  (
    "COLUMN1"           CHAR(10 BYTE) CONSTRAINT "SOMETHING_TABLE_COLUMN1_CK" NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "COLUMN2"       CHAR(10 BYTE),
    "COLUMN3"          CHAR(2 BYTE),
    "COLUMN4"    VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)
  )

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_SOMETHING_TABLE" ON "SOMETHING_TABLE"
  (
    "COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3"
  )
```

And my Hibernate Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOMETHING_TABLE")
public class Something_tableImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "COLUMN1")
    private String column1 = null;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COLUMN2")
    private String column2 = null;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COLUMN3")
    private String column3 = null;

    @Column(name = "COLUMN4")
    private String column4 = null;

    public String getColumn1() {
        return column1;
    }

    public void setColumn1(String column1) {
        this.column1 = column1;
    }

    public String getColumn2() {
        return column2;
    }

    public void setColumn2(String column2) {
        this.column2 = column2;
    }

    public String getColumn3() {
        return column3;
    }

    public void setColumn3(String column3) {
        this.column3 = column3;
    }

    public String getColumn4() {
        return column4;
    }

    public void setColumn4(String column4) {
        this.column4 = column4;
    }
}
```

Then I create a hibernate query, more or less like this one:

`public Something_table GetSomethingFrom(String column1, String column2, String column3) {
            Criteria queryCriteria = myDAO.getCriteria(Something_tableImpl.class);
            queryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("column1", column1));
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(column2)) {
                queryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("column2", column2));
            }
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(column3)) {
                queryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("column3", column3));
            }
            List < Something_table > somethingTableList = queryCriteria.list();
            if (!somethingTableList.isEmpty()) {
                return somethingTableList.get(0);
            }
        return null;
    }`

Then `somethingTableList` size is 1, and the element this contains is null. But in the DataBase I was able to get 1 row with valid values.

So ¿Why am I getting null values?

**EDIT1**:
I can't add `@IdClass` annotation, because of in the DB exist rows that contains the values related to `column1` and `column2` as null. N̶o̶r̶ ̶r̶e̶m̶o̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶`̶@̶I̶d̶`̶ ̶o̶v̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶s̶e̶ ̶3̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶u̶m̶n̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶e̶n̶t̶i̶t̶y̶ ̶b̶e̶c̶a̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶w̶a̶s̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶O̶R̶A̶C̶L̶E̶.

**EDIT2**:
Could it be happening due to I'm not overriding **hashcode()** and **equals()**?

Comment: column3 is used twice in pojo, i guess it should be column4

Comment: you need to add the entire code used for retrieving the list, Something_table class and datatype and data of column1 used as restriction.

Comment: Ok NP. But what do you mean with the last part? That about "datatype and data of column1 used as a restriction".

Comment: What is column1 here? queryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("column1", column1)); what is its datatype and what data are you storing in that variable? The second column1 without quote.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad I just updated the description.

Comment: Actually I `@Id` over `column1` and `column2` can be removed. At least there's no problem. I'm checking if I'm retrieving the same values  as when `@Id` was over `column1` and `column2`.

Comment: I'm thinking this issue could be triggered because of I'm not implementing 'hashcode()' and 'equals()'. Any thoughts?